# Turn off csrf/authenticity_token protection on your login page

Tags: ruby-on-rails, security, ruby-on-rails-3.2, csrf

We are considering turning off csrf/authenticity token protection on our login page. (likely with a skip_before_filter on the login post action). This would allow us to post from a static html page on our site.  What are the security implications of this?  It seems that if we turn it off for only login post, there isn't much malicious that could be done.

Comment: @apneadiving Wouldn't a bot be able to do that already? It'd require loading the page each time to get a new token, but still. CSRF doesn't throttle login attempts as far as I know, it just protects against replay attacks

Comment: And with a csrf token it's a 2 line mechanize script. Csrf is about credential hijacking which is clearly not a concern here

Comment: @apneadiving You seem to not understand what CSRF actually is.

Comment: @Gumbo: thanks for your comment, it made me read the definition in details and I must admit I didn't have the whole picture! :)

Answer (score 2):

CSRF tokens are not designed to block bots!
CSRF (cross site request forgery) is an attack where a spoofed formular/url is triggered e.g. by an invisible iframe. On weak systems this lets an attacke change configurations on homepages.

Let me describe a sample attack:
An administrator of a webshop is logged in into his admin account. An attacker now sends him a mail containing a link to a fake homepage. When the admin enters the page a JavaScript sends data to the URL where he would send a form to create a new admin user, and the JavaScript sends all the needed data like a new username, a new password, etc. The admin is logged in, so from the point of the webshop the admin creates a regular new admin account. From the point of the admin nothing happenes, because all happened in the background. CSRF tokens prevent forms from being attacked in ways like this.

You can read a lot more about CSRF on wikipedia: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_request_forgery